# Изменить свойство css, используя animate()

Tags: css, jquery

> box-shadow:1px 2px 3px **0** rgba(15, 65, 33, 0.08), 5px 10px 20px 0 rgba(18, 43, 26, 0.12);

Как используя animate() изменить изменить за 5 сек. от 0 до 20px значение выделенное жирным шрифтом?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я верно Вас понял, то вот решение при помощи `@keyframes{ to {...} }` и `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`, который остановит анимацию на последнем кадре :

```css
div {
  margin: 50px;
  box-shadow:
    1px 2px 3px 0 rgba(15, 65, 33, 0.08), 
    5px 10px 20px 0 rgba(18, 43, 26, 0.12);
  animation: shadow 5s;   
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes shadow {
  to {
    box-shadow:
      1px 2px 3px 20px rgba(15, 65, 33, 0.08), 
      5px 10px 20px 0 rgba(18, 43, 26, 0.12);
  }
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```